# passwordless ssh works one way, but not the other

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 3 CentOS VM  and am trying to setup passwordless ssh from any host to any other host. (call them `db01`,`db02`,`dbmgr`)

I have the RSA public keys copied to .ssh/authorized_keys 
i.e

`db01`->.ssh/authorized_keys has entries of public keys from `db02`, `dbmgr`

`db02`->.ssh/authorized_keys has entries of public keys from `db01`, `dbmgr`

`dbmgr`->.ssh/authorized_keys has entries of public keys from `db01`, `db02`

I have verified that the public key strings across the host

```
[abhyas_db01@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsT8zUe4or3VCN8C1k0XVyQ9erpEiXDKORnS9rujBTDw1bFdCDnQLngteu+dbHIeZ2O8vrtH6cJVdqSjhGJjlswnhOdH6IfxIrKDb+Rug4LhxSei6jTxH3gq0vmrPzsoy14J/Q1xxAEbtIyc2J6JmupKf/bmafITnijvFUgZ70xlzVs1cmzAaU6+A/te9Oc+HCvpGzDLLUNSQUq8rRhAm8IFDy3+qHk+h2+BQCMx0uDRKGaxXhqur/1l0nzJNL49gANTF4LYmdqU7Vb07Vm7BbIdKwxgc2njAqOPfhE3iBmAeOmmq715Dhf2OO4DY/OdnDSFDo+MZAscf/tk1ZA0hvw== abhyas_db01@abhyas.db01

[abhyas_db02@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEApkPWB3L9LJNyUW/iFKlJGKTSeIviBRrP6lTvmw7wPGMEto5TFvie4vogaGv6euUNLQiM7HdneNCoZjoeMDgOl7od9ZMZpXNslSX/tPZI0Ha55Mx2T5l7ka4t/Uzm/rzYz3GgNmag8o8buKDCfjXzAMJWU7DnkLFf04rFenzQC3twTIfQKXXnnOo5Fka1f6110xEDuHaRZ24Fesp7T67joSECwjTJvPfFXT3EUMCAXmuzBsFc2fXQmPM/MSGvrBY6pj6ntGQ6+R8OR1yS/2sZudmSb2uxsRnKdhue9E20HEE/tiyL6IByY9s70KRsNarB7GGvVPfZvTXu/N8/TkNHaQ== abhyas_db02@abhyas.db02
[abhyas_db02@abhyas ~]$ 

[abhyas_mgr@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfc2PvbGmOX638qhFh2h2oZ3ZzP8r177BnclMe22xi+Fe8tj/RGVM5NQStAXulBlwVc2KSWgkAt5+oe7nDoVENWaetapTBaMwJcxiGyJPs7SIrcVOUI4CDaHbXQAM2Bs7EjsGfY7LlFyOCZZWnwEjRMW23wnis6200grleZftrU07Tk05v1rfihlY2pm2dV1mMckoyUOP7gn8MDvLCj6DlFPwcGw6h5siIU0UU0wiSxg8Q3zXdFaXnDXGp3lFic71TzfPidmimu8k2PDZhikz21ypxn1YaDluYJ6Wn+zTgkNFrdV6T7tT27RIzWXAJHT9OMnhpKFa+HTxbTKlecxqw== abhyas_mgr@abhyas.dbmgr
[abhyas_mgr@abhyas ~]$ 


[abhyas_db01@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEApkPWB3L9LJNyUW/iFKlJGKTSeIviBRrP6lTvmw7wPGMEto5TFvie4vogaGv6euUNLQiM7HdneNCoZjoeMDgOl7od9ZMZpXNslSX/tPZI0Ha55Mx2T5l7ka4t/Uzm/rzYz3GgNmag8o8buKDCfjXzAMJWU7DnkLFf04rFenzQC3twTIfQKXXnnOo5Fka1f6110xEDuHaRZ24Fesp7T67joSECwjTJvPfFXT3EUMCAXmuzBsFc2fXQmPM/MSGvrBY6pj6ntGQ6+R8OR1yS/2sZudmSb2uxsRnKdhue9E20HEE/tiyL6IByY9s70KRsNarB7GGvVPfZvTXu/N8/TkNHaQ== abhyas_db02@abhyas.db02
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfc2PvbGmOX638qhFh2h2oZ3ZzP8r177BnclMe22xi+Fe8tj/RGVM5NQStAXulBlwVc2KSWgkAt5+oe7nDoVENWaetapTBaMwJcxiGyJPs7SIrcVOUI4CDaHbXQAM2Bs7EjsGfY7LlFyOCZZWnwEjRMW23wnis6200grleZftrU07Tk05v1rfihlY2pm2dV1mMckoyUOP7gn8MDvLCj6DlFPwcGw6h5siIU0UU0wiSxg8Q3zXdFaXnDXGp3lFic71TzfPidmimu8k2PDZhikz21ypxn1YaDluYJ6Wn+zTgkNFrdV6T7tT27RIzWXAJHT9OMnhpKFa+HTxbTKlecxqw== abhyas_mgr@abhyas.dbmgr


[abhyas_db02@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsT8zUe4or3VCN8C1k0XVyQ9erpEiXDKORnS9rujBTDw1bFdCDnQLngteu+dbHIeZ2O8vrtH6cJVdqSjhGJjlswnhOdH6IfxIrKDb+Rug4LhxSei6jTxH3gq0vmrPzsoy14J/Q1xxAEbtIyc2J6JmupKf/bmafITnijvFUgZ70xlzVs1cmzAaU6+A/te9Oc+HCvpGzDLLUNSQUq8rRhAm8IFDy3+qHk+h2+BQCMx0uDRKGaxXhqur/1l0nzJNL49gANTF4LYmdqU7Vb07Vm7BbIdKwxgc2njAqOPfhE3iBmAeOmmq715Dhf2OO4DY/OdnDSFDo+MZAscf/tk1ZA0hvw== abhyas_db01@abhyas.db01
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfc2PvbGmOX638qhFh2h2oZ3ZzP8r177BnclMe22xi+Fe8tj/RGVM5NQStAXulBlwVc2KSWgkAt5+oe7nDoVENWaetapTBaMwJcxiGyJPs7SIrcVOUI4CDaHbXQAM2Bs7EjsGfY7LlFyOCZZWnwEjRMW23wnis6200grleZftrU07Tk05v1rfihlY2pm2dV1mMckoyUOP7gn8MDvLCj6DlFPwcGw6h5siIU0UU0wiSxg8Q3zXdFaXnDXGp3lFic71TzfPidmimu8k2PDZhikz21ypxn1YaDluYJ6Wn+zTgkNFrdV6T7tT27RIzWXAJHT9OMnhpKFa+HTxbTKlecxqw== abhyas_mgr@abhyas.dbmgr
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfc2PvbGmOX638qhFh2h2oZ3ZzP8r177BnclMe22xi+Fe8tj/RGVM5NQStAXulBlwVc2KSWgkAt5+oe7nDoVENWaetapTBaMwJcxiGyJPs7SIrcVOUI4CDaHbXQAM2Bs7EjsGfY7LlFyOCZZWnwEjRMW23wnis6200grleZftrU07Tk05v1rfihlY2pm2dV1mMckoyUOP7gn8MDvLCj6DlFPwcGw6h5siIU0UU0wiSxg8Q3zXdFaXnDXGp3lFic71TzfPidmimu8k2PDZhikz21ypxn1YaDluYJ6Wn+zTgkNFrdV6T7tT27RIzWXAJHT9OMnhpKFa+HTxbTKlecxqw== abhyas_mgr@abhyas.dbmgr



[abhyas_mgr@abhyas ~]$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsT8zUe4or3VCN8C1k0XVyQ9erpEiXDKORnS9rujBTDw1bFdCDnQLngteu+dbHIeZ2O8vrtH6cJVdqSjhGJjlswnhOdH6IfxIrKDb+Rug4LhxSei6jTxH3gq0vmrPzsoy14J/Q1xxAEbtIyc2J6JmupKf/bmafITnijvFUgZ70xlzVs1cmzAaU6+A/te9Oc+HCvpGzDLLUNSQUq8rRhAm8IFDy3+qHk+h2+BQCMx0uDRKGaxXhqur/1l0nzJNL49gANTF4LYmdqU7Vb07Vm7BbIdKwxgc2njAqOPfhE3iBmAeOmmq715Dhf2OO4DY/OdnDSFDo+MZAscf/tk1ZA0hvw== abhyas_db01@abhyas.db01
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEApkPWB3L9LJNyUW/iFKlJGKTSeIviBRrP6lTvmw7wPGMEto5TFvie4vogaGv6euUNLQiM7HdneNCoZjoeMDgOl7od9ZMZpXNslSX/tPZI0Ha55Mx2T5l7ka4t/Uzm/rzYz3GgNmag8o8buKDCfjXzAMJWU7DnkLFf04rFenzQC3twTIfQKXXnnOo5Fka1f6110xEDuHaRZ24Fesp7T67joSECwjTJvPfFXT3EUMCAXmuzBsFc2fXQmPM/MSGvrBY6pj6ntGQ6+R8OR1yS/2sZudmSb2uxsRnKdhue9E20HEE/tiyL6IByY9s70KRsNarB7GGvVPfZvTXu/N8/TkNHaQ== abhyas_db02@abhyas.db02
```

And I am able to ssh to `db01` to `db02` and the other way around without a password and I am able to ssh to `db01` and `db02` from `dbmgr` without a password.

But trying to ssh to `dbmgr` from `db01` or `db02` asks for a password.

I am not sure what I am missing.

EDIT:Solved it, by looking at the logs. The logs indicated that there was indeed a permission issue.

```
 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3787]: debug1: userauth-request for user abhyas_mgr service ssh-connection method none
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3787]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "abhyas_mgr"
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "abhyas.db01"
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3787]: debug1: userauth-request for user abhyas_mgr service ssh-connection method publickey
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3787]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3787]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: trying public key file /home/abhyas_mgr/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/abhyas_mgr/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: trying public key file /home/abhyas_mgr/.ssh/authorized_keys2
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/abhyas_mgr/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: Failed publickey for abhyas_mgr from 192.168.102.131 port 54518 ssh2
^C
```

Comment: did you check to access rights to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? What does the `sshd` server writes in debug mode to your keys?

Comment: where do i check the sshd output and how do i run it in debug mode ? the access to authorized_keys must be correct otherwise i would also face the same problem in sshing to the other host.

Comment: put `LogLevel DEBUG3` in you `sshd_config`, restart `sshd` and you should see the logs in some of your log files `/var/log/secure`, `/var/log/messages` or so.

Comment: thanks. let me try that and see if i can find anything out.

Comment: The logging helped a lot! Thanks!!  "Sep  6 14:13:01 localhost sshd[3786]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/abhyas_mgr/.ssh/authorized_keys". I was able to fix the problem now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually indicative of a permissions issue. Make sure that your permissions are set correctly on the following directories and files:

- /home/username/ - permissons should be at least 700 or 750
- /home/username/.ssh/ - permissions should be at least 500
- /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys - permissions should be at least 400

Permissions can be set using the chmod command. For example:

```
chmod 500 /home/username/.ssh
```

As Luis Colorado pointed out below there is also a maximum permission level that OpenSSH allows. If it's set too loosely (such as 777) you will not be able to log in. See [the OpenSSH faq](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.14) for more information.

Comment: why 700 or 500 ? why is execute important for the owner ? btw, the folders already have those, i am just curious to know.

Comment: Folders need those otherwise you will not be able to list files inside. You can find many questions like this around here.

Comment: Generally the home directory should be accessible to the owner (person logging in). The execute bit allows you to enter the directory and access files in it. Are you wanting something different?

Comment: Restrictions on home directory don't hold as such... you can share your personal directory contents with some `777` permissions, and be able to login with ssh.  Permissions for `.ssh` and `.ssh/*` is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I added that additional information to my post above. Also, on that post it says that 777 on the home directory can be an issue.